# Typescript adding "| null" to return type of Promise.all

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an async TS function that makes a request and casts the response data to a `boolean` and returns it, but in the calling function VS Code is telling me the return value is `boolean | null` when I make the call in `Promise.all`. Here's the code:

The function:

```
import apiAxios from "../apiAxios";

export default async function doesAssignmentHaveTakes(
  assignmentId: number
): Promise<boolean> {
  const response = await apiAxios.get(`/assignments/${assignmentId}/has-takes`);

  return !!response.data;
}
```

And the caller:

```
import React, { FC, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components/macro";
import AssignmentForm, {
  Props as AssignmentFormProps,
  Value as AssignmentFormValue
} from "./AssignmentForm";
import useAsyncEffect from "../utils/useAsyncEffect";
import getAssignmentById from "../api/assignments/getAssignmentById";
import doesAssignmentHaveTakes from "../api/assignmentTakes/doesAssignmentHaveTakes";

interface Props extends AssignmentFormProps {
  assignmentId: number;
  onSubmit(value: Value): any;
}

export interface Value extends AssignmentFormValue {
  assignmentId: number;
}

const EditAssignmentForm: FC<Props> = props => {
  const { assignmentId, onSubmit, ...rest } = props;
  const [showEditWarning, setShowEditWarning] = useState(false);
  const [initialValue, setInitialValue] = useState<AssignmentFormValue | null>(
    null
  );

  useAsyncEffect(
    async isCancelled => {
      const [fetchedAssignment, hasTakes] = await Promise.all([
        getAssignmentById(assignmentId),
        doesAssignmentHaveTakes(assignmentId)
      ]);

      if (!fetchedAssignment) {
        // TODO: Alert parent component?
        return;
      }

      const value: Value = {
        assignmentId: fetchedAssignment.id,
        assignment: {
          title: fetchedAssignment.title,
          subTitle: fetchedAssignment.subTitle
        },
        sets: fetchedAssignment.sets
          .map(set => ({
            id: set.id,
            index: set.index,
            questions: set.questions
              .map(question => ({
                id: question.id,
                index: question.index,
                isPractice: question.isPractice,
                questionText: question.questionText,
                inputType: question.inputType,
                questionImage: question.questionImage,
                sampleResponseText: question.sampleResponseText,
                sampleResponseImage: question.sampleResponseImage
              }))
              .sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index),
            learningTarget: set.learningTarget,
            isExampleCorrect: set.isExampleCorrect,
            exampleImage: set.exampleImage,
            character: set.character
          }))
          .sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index)
      };

      if (!isCancelled()) {
        setInitialValue(value);
        setShowEditWarning(hasTakes);
      }
    },
    [assignmentId]
  );

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    (value: AssignmentFormValue) => {
      onSubmit({
        ...value,
        assignmentId
      });
    },
    [onSubmit, assignmentId]
  );

  if (!initialValue) {
    // Loading...
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <AssignmentForm
      {...rest}
      initialValue={initialValue}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    />
  );
};

export default styled(EditAssignmentForm)``;
```

The specific lines with the issue:

```
  const [fetchedAssignment, hasTakes] = await Promise.all([
    getAssignmentById(assignmentId),
    doesAssignmentHaveTakes(assignmentId)
  ]);
```

And

```
setShowEditWarning(hasTakes);
```

The TS error:

```
TypeScript error in /Users/james/projects/math-by-example/client/src/components/EditAssignmentForm.tsx(71,28):
Argument of type 'boolean | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<boolean>'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<boolean>'.  TS2345

    69 |       if (!isCancelled()) {
    70 |         setInitialValue(value);
  > 71 |         setShowEditWarning(hasTakes);
       |                            ^
    72 |       }
    73 |     },
    74 |     [assignmentId]
```

And some screenshots of the error in VS Code

[image: VS Code type tooltip]

[image: VS Code error tooltip]

Why does TS add `null` to the resolved types of `Promise.all`?

Comment: you can use assertion like this `setShowEditWarning(hasTakes as boolean)` 
https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I'm mostly trying to understand *why* `| null` is being appended to the type. Not so much looking for a solution to the failed build.

Comment: I have tried to check it on my side, Please have a look at the screenshots,
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16IP64lQAcbv5mppBLba8kWq72Lckqj-g/view
I think you somewhere determined it can be boolean or null

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan I definitely didn't though. I'm explicitly defining the return type of `doesAssignmentHaveTakes` as `Promise<boolean>`. I'm also casting the result to a boolean with `!!`, and if I move the call to `doesAssignmentHaveTakes` out of `Promise.all`, the return type is showing as just `boolean`. I'm certain this has something to do with `Promise.all`. If I was actually returning `boolean | null`, TS would error because I've annotated the function with `Promise<boolean>` not `Promise<boolean | null>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The solution is to add `as const` to the array you pass to `Promise.all`.**

#### Explanation

The problem is not with the typing of `Promise.all` or a bug in the compiler. The issue is what TypeScript does by default with an array. Consider this:

```
const q = [1, "a"];
```

The default type inference for `q` will be `(string | number)[]`. Even though you have a number as the first position, and a string as the second, TypeScript infers that *all* positions can be either a string or a number. If you want TypeScript to treat the array as a tuple and assign to each position the narrowest type possible, you can do:

```
const q = [1, "a"] as const;
```

TS will infer a type of `readonly [1, "a"]` for this array. So `q` can have only the number 1 in the first position and the string `"a"` in the second. (It is also readonly but that's a side issue here.) This was introduced in [TypeScript 3.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions).

Ok, what does this have to do with your case? When you pass your array to `Promise.all` TypeScript is using the kind of type inference I've shown in my first example. `Promise.all` sees an array in which each item can take the union of all values that the items can take. If you use `as const` then the inference will be like the second case I've shown above, and this will be reflected accordingly in the type that `Promise.all` gets. Again, there's **no problem** with `Promise.all`'s typing. It works with what it gets: bad typing in, bad typing out.

Here's an illustration (also in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?useDefineForClassFields=true&allowUnreachableCode=true&allowUnusedLabels=true&downlevelIteration=true&noEmitHelpers=true&noUnusedLocals=true&noUnusedParameters=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=8#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsL2ACgJQBcMACgE7oC2qIApgDwjKmoQDmMAPjBAgDa8A+GAG8YpGsgSksAIjjp0MgNwwAvgCh1oSLEQoMWOACN8RMpWr0jC3jWAQho8ZOkwmCGio1bw0eEig0TBgKYBZTEnIqWjoAN3RUABNHdRg0mFtkGGAiRmY2Tm4+XiVU9MyYIyJrdFt7UrK0gHommAAlGgp0WJo3AAtqGBlQGChMRhlsiET+3rHE3oB3TAByLLGKAAdUWwA6RpgAbWAAGkqAXRgAXmzFsKzzaJpd4H4cQ7hcPDPjfEuRsYQRh4BrpUbjWrPXjoVg4U6VEHqbyhcIgoA)):

```
async function fa(): Promise<string | null> { return "foo"; }

async function fb(): Promise<boolean> { return true; }

async function main(): Promise<void> {
    let a: string | null;
    let b: boolean;

    // Remove this "as const" and the code won't compile.
    [a, b] = await Promise.all([fa(), fb()] as const);

    console.log(a, b);
}

main();
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved from ts 3.9+ ([release note](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#improvements-in-inference-and-promiseall)), upgrade to 3.9 and you will not see this error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the type definitions for `Promise.all`, [take a look](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/9c71eaf59040ae75343da8cdff01344020f5bba2/tests/cases/compiler/bluebirdStaticThis.ts#L49). The return type of the `.all` always try to make a union of the array promises generic types.

Probably your other function `getAssignmentById` can return `null`, so the `Promise.all` will infer a return type of `[something | null, boolean | null]`. It is possibly a bug with the TS compiler, I am not sure. I made a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=42&pln=5&pc=46#code/IYZwngdgxgBAZgV2gFwJYHsLyVAggCgEoAuGABQCd0BbVEAUwB4AjddAG3uAgD4YBvALAAoGGJgV6yBBSyUadegDpJIDgDd6%20ZBQT1CAbhEBfESNCRYiFBizWoAISKl5tBo3TMAVvSjIYAD4wEAjs7HxCouKS0rLkVG7Kqhpa-MaGJmbC%20BbQMEQwALwRIuIwUJgg-gDawAA0zAC6RTDAAO7AqP6uikrAYfjV9gSEddjQToSNhCaEREA) with the same conditions to see the inference in practice, take a look at how it infers the generic types on Promise constructor, then remove the `null` from the return type of `funcB` and see the `Promise.all` type again... it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Pedro's answer that Promise.all doesn't deal with different return types out of the box.

You can try declaring the return type of your Promise like this:

```
const [fetchedAssignment, hasTakes] = await Promise.all<string | null, boolean>([
    getAssignmentById(assignmentId),
    doesAssignmentHaveTakes(assignmentId)
]);
```